# regex - get content inside matching braces

Tags: r, regex

I have a text of the form:

```
text <- "\\examples{afunction(x = list()){\nx<-3\n}y<-2 server <- function(input, output, session) {\n  output$res_bttn1 <- renderPrint({input$bttn1})\n}\n}"
```

I would like to obtain the content of `\\examples{}` (without the `\n` at the end), i.e

```
"afunction(x = list()){\nx<-3\n}y<-2 server <- function(input, output, session) {\n  output$res_bttn1 <- renderPrint({input$bttn1})\n}"
```

The issue is that there are other braces inside `\\examples{}`. Therefore, I think I have to find a regex to detect which `}` closes `\\examples{` (but I'm open to other suggestions on how to have the same result).

How can I do that? A base R solution is preferred.

Comment: Will this work? `sub('examples\\{(.*)\n\\}', '\\1', text)` matching until last `'\n'` ?

Comment: That is good for this example, but I'm not sure that there will always be a `\n` before the final `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
\\examples({([^{}]*?(?:(?1)[^{}]*?)*)\s*})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBwWE8/2).

**Details**

- `\\examples` - an `\examples` string
- `({([^{}]*?(?:(?1)[^{}]*?)*)\s*})` - Group 1 (it is necessary since a regex subroutine `(?1)` will recurse this subpattern):

  - `{` - a `{` char
  - `([^{}]*?(?:(?1)[^{}]*?)*)` - Group 2 (the value you need):

    - `[^{}]*?` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` as few as possible
    - `(?:(?1)[^{}]*?)*` - zero or more occurrences of the whole Group 1 pattern followed with zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` as few as possible
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (trims the whitespace before the trailing `}`)
  - `}` - a `}` char

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/ppKQ8G):

```r
text <- "\\examples{afunction(x = list()){\nx<-3\n}y<-2 server <- function(input, output, session) {\n  output$res_bttn1 <- renderPrint({input$bttn1})\n}\n}"
pattern = "\\\\examples({([^{}]*?(?:(?1)[^{}]*?)*)\\s*})"
unlist(regmatches(text, regexec(pattern, text, perl=TRUE)))[3]
# => [1] "afunction(x = list()){\nx<-3\n}y<-2 server <- function(input, output, session) {\n  output$res_bttn1 <- renderPrint({input$bttn1})\n}"
```